# Bootstrap Dropdown doesn't show value send via Ajax

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-5

When i send via ajax a query to set values in a dropdown list as selected, the dropdown list doesn't show the value even i see the value in the source of the page.

Here my blanc Dropdown option :

[image]

Here is what i get in the source of the page

```
<select class="form-select mb-3" id="label" name="label">
                                        
    <option value="75000" id="code" selected="">PARIS</option>

</select>
```

Here is my code:

```
<select class="form-select mb-3" id="label" name="label" required>

   <option value="" id="code" selected></option>

<?php  while ($row = $stmtGetLabel->fetch()) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['code'] ?>"><?php echo $row['label'] ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
                                        
...

$(document).on('click', '.update , #act', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url:"inc/functions/ActRef.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{id:id},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#mymodal').modal('show');
            $('#label').val(data.code);
            $('#code').attr('value', data.code).html(data.label);               
            $('#id').val(id);
            $('#action').val("EDIT");
            $('#operation').val("edit");
        }
    })
});
```

I use Bootstrap 5.2.0

any ideas?

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @achillix , did you check if `data.code` has proper value ?

Comment: Hello @Swati, yes, that was the trick. Thank you very much